# ASP.NET control rendering

Tags: asp.net

I'm wondering how the HyperLink control used in the following code example renderes to html displaying the text contained in the welcome.Text variable.

The same thing for the link to the sign-up page.

Since I assume this script doesn't run every time a page request is made, I also wonder in which cases this script gets run in the sample application.

```cs
<script language="C#" runat="server">

    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            welcome.Text = "Welcome " + User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else {
            // not signed in yet, add a link to signin page
            welcome.Text = "please sign in!";
            welcome.NavigateUrl = "signin.aspx";
        }
    }

</script>

<asp:HyperLink id="welcome" runat="server" maintainstate="false">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

**Edit.**

To be more precise, how does the HyperLink control know how to render the variable welcome.Text?

Is it the case that when a control is declared, the ControlName.Text, if declared, is always rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page_Load should run every time the page is requested. Your HyperLink will be rendered as `<a href="signin.aspx">please sign in!</a>` for unauthenticated user and where as `<a href="">Welcome LoginUserName</a>` for authenticated login.
Is it what you are looking for. If not please describe more details.

Comment: I've made an edit to include some more details relating to my problem. My main confusion arises from how a Control knows how and when to render its <ControlName>.Text variable to html, when the Control.Text variable is declared.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I believe you are trying to understand asp.net page life cycle. Generally, Request -> Init -> Load -> Render -> Unload. Direct answer to your question in layman terms, it loads your controls in aspx file and overwrite the controls properties where you put in Page_Load event. After that, rendered to html, unload and response to client(browser). Mostly, there is Pre_ stage in each cycle (eg. pre_init, Pre_render so fault). More details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx